# itext XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS and generate multi language HTML page

Tags: itext, pdf-generation, multilingual, xmlworker

Can someone help to explain what is `XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS` for? Not much explanations in the API documentation.

Also, I have seen some examples on `XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS`, mostly used with `XMLWorkerFontProvider.register("font file path")` to generate  multi language file for known text/fonts, in the case where the text is dynamic (i.e.: can be a mixture of any language ), how should this be handled?

I tried to register all the google noto fonts that can support a lot of languages but the page was not rendered correctly.

This is my multi language test text:

```
<h4>a test |cs 测试|th ทดสอบ |j テスト|k 테스트|h מִבְחָן|a اختبار|p تست|h परीक्षण |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a</h4>
```

And this is what I get in pdf: (only english)

```
a test |cs |th |j |k |h |a |p |h |r |ct |a
```

When I specified Noto Sans CJK SC font family:

```
<h4 style="font-family: Noto Sans CJK SC;">a test |cs 测试|th ทดสอบ |j テスト|k 테스트|h מִבְחָן|a اختبار|p تست|h परीक्षण |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a</h4>
```

I get chinese, japanese, korean, russian and english:

```
a test |cs 测试|th |j テスト|k 테스트|h |a |p |h |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a
```

When I specified Noto Sans Thai font family:

```
<h4 style="font-family: Noto Sans Thai;">a test |cs 测试|th ทดสอบ |j テスト|k 테스트|h מִבְחָן|a اختبار|p تست|h परीक्षण |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a</h4>
```

I get Thai only:

```
ทดสอบ
```

When I specified Arial:

```
<h4 style="font-family: Arial;">a test |cs 测试|th ทดสอบ |j テスト|k 테스트|h מִבְחָן|a اختبار|p تست|h परीक्षण |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a</h4>
```

I get english,arabic, hebrew, persian and russian only

```
a test |cs |th |j |k |h ןָחְבִמ |a رابتخا |p تست |h |r контрольная работа|ct |a
```

if I specified more than one font-family:

```
<h4 style="font-family: Arial, Noto Sans CJK SC, Noto Sans Thai;">a test |cs 测试|th ทดสอบ |j テスト|k 테스트|h מִבְחָן|a اختبار|p تست|h परीक्षण |r контрольная работа|ct 測試|a</h4>
```

the result is same as Arial case above (Is it because Arial is first font-family entry?)

```
a test |cs |th |j |k |h ןָחְבִמ |a رابتخا |p تست |h |r контрольная работа|ct |a
```

What should I do to get the right output?  I am registering all the google Noto  fonts  with `XMLHelperFontProvider.registerDirectory("<Google Noto fonts path>")`.