# Using Multiple Noto fonts in HTML to PDF using iTextPDF

Tags: android, html, itext

I am using the iText library for converting HTML to PDF.

Now My HTML contains multiple language and currency symbols.
Languages like Arabic , Hindi , Gujarati , Malayalam.
Symbols like Indian Rupee (₹) .

I am registering Arial Unicode MS fonts in ITextPDF like

```
String FONT = "assets/fonts/arial_unicode.ttf";

XMLWorkerFontProvider fontImp = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS);
fontImp.register(FONT);
```

And defining in Html in body:

```
"font-family:"Arial Unicode MS";
```

**Now everything works fine all languages are displayed but rupee symbol is not displayed**.

I have heard of google Noto fonts which is designed for particular languages
as : https://www.google.com/get/noto/

Now My question is How to define all the required Noto Fonts in HTML :

as I can do like

```
 "  font-family:"Noto Sans","Noto Naksh Arabic","Noto Sans gujarati";
```

But when I do this it takes the first font only and try to display only that particular font in html to Pdf.

How can I use all the fonts and my PDF should use all the fonts and display accordingly.

I have tried each and every possibility but nothing is helping also Arial Unicode MS is huge of 22 MB and has no rupee symbol.

UPDATE : What I was doing with font family is not possible as stated here : https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/3394 .

Also more Detail for this question can be seen here : [itext XMLWorkerFontProvider.DONTLOOKFORFONTS and generate multi language HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43108318/itext-xmlworkerfontprovider-dontlookforfonts-and-generate-multi-language-html-pa)

Comment: You're using an old version of iText. I'm pretty sure this is solved in iText 7 and the pdfHTML add-on: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml

Comment: iText7 I think is not supported for Android